# asp.net condition statement in sitefinity widget template

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

I feel like i am close to getting this but i am getting a compilation error. I am using a widget template in sitefinity. I am trying to use a conditional statement based on three sets of radio buttons. Basically im trying to see if the text needs to be left right or center, dark or light and if the list item is the first to be shown. I think i am close with using the <%# eval %> but may be wrong by using the &&.

here is an example of the code...

```
<%# Eval("TextPosition") == 0 && Eval("ColorChoice") == 0 &&  Eval("IsFirst") == 0 ?
    <li ></li>
 %>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be incomplete. the usage of the ternary operator is as follows:

```
(condition) ? valueiftrue : valueiffalse;
```

there is nothing after the ? in your code. what are you trying to achieve based on the conditions?

Comment: Text position has three values Color Choice has 2 and Is first has 2. i want to see if a person selects left dark and it is first then display the list item  with certain classes...if they choose right dark and is first do it with right class instead of the first

Comment: i think i did figure out instead of checking if the radio button choice equals 0, 1 or 2 check to see if it equals the text associated with those values like Left, Center or Right.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<li style='display:<%# ((int)Eval("TextPosition") == 0) && ((int)Eval("ColorChoice") == 0) &&  ((int)Eval("IsFirst") == 0) ? "none" : "block" %>'></li>
```

Hope this helps.